# Create Heroku app with ruby 2.1.0 and rails 4.2.0 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to create a app on Heroku, but when I try to push to Heroku, I get this error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing Ruby ruby-2.1.0
remote:  !     For supported Ruby versions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does your gem file specify the ruby version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://news.railstutorial.org/heroku-update/

"Heroku’s recently announced Cedar-14 stack is incompatible with all but the most recent version of each Ruby sequence, meaning (for example) that it works with Ruby 2.1.4 but not with 2.1.3. Unfortunately, this makes it incompatible with the local Ruby versions on many systems"

So it looks like you need to update your Ruby to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.1.0 is not supported by Heroku.  Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions for a list of supported versions.